# Scanf every number in input until user input 0

Tags: c, scanf, prime-factoring

I need to make a program that asks user to input an indeterminate count of numbers and end the input with number 0.

After input I need to do prime factorization of every number from input.

I have this now, but it only works for first number from input and then ends the program.

```
int main()
{        
    long long number,div;       
    while(scanf("%lli",&number)==1){
        printf("The prime factors of %lli are: \n",number);

        div = 2;

        while(number!=0){
            if(number%div!=0)
                div = div + 1;
            else {
                number = number / div;
                printf("%lli ",div);
                if(number==1)
                    break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please show us what have you tired.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Questions that simply state the problem do not get answered here, unless they show your best attempt at solving them independently.

Comment: That seems like a nice exercise. What have you tried? How did your attempt work? Or not work? What problems do you have with your code? Also, I recommend you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Look at the `return 0;` statement at the end of the loop just after the `printf("\n");`. Does this ring a bell ?

Answer (score 1):

```
      int main()
      {        
          long long number,div;       
          while(scanf("%lli",&number)==1){
         printf("The prime factors of %lli are: \n",number);

         div = 2;

        while(number!=0){
            if(number%div!=0)
               div = div + 1;
           else {
              number = number / div;
              printf("%lli ",div);
               if(number==1)
                break;
            }
        }
      printf("\n");
   // return 0;   // you should remove this return as it cause to exit the program 
     }
     return 0;
  }
```

Return statement cause to exit the program . Or try to return from where function got called .

So please try above code.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the loop condition to break out on 0:

```
int main()
{
    long long number,div;       
    int loop = ( 1 == scanf("%lli",&number) ) && ( 0 != number );
    while( loop )
    {
        printf("The prime factors of %lli are: \n",number);
        // ..
        printf("\n");
        loop = ( 1 == scanf("%lli",&number) ) && ( 0 != number );
    }
    return 0;
}
```